# Unable to get JSON response form Ajax request

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I am having WordPress feed in Json format(https://blog.piscessportfishing.com/feed/json/) but I am unbale to read it using ajax request.
In success I don't get anything with data variable. instead it gives error in alert.

here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',       
    url: "https://blog.piscessportfishing.com/feed/json/",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {},
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);            
    },
    error: function (Request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Request=" + Request.responseText + "\ntextStatus=" + textStatus + "\nerrorThrown=" + errorThrown);
    }        
  });
```

Comment: Do you have any CORS errors, which means you cannot able to access other domain URL?
FYI, you should add headers for all type requests, it should be a proper structure

Comment: @HemaRamasamy yes the issue was with CORS thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error :

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://blog.piscessportfishing.com/feed/json/' from origin 'http://XYZ' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Use it to enable CORS on your WordPress website :
In your functions.php file add the following code.

```html
header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . esc_url_raw( site_url() ) );
```

Documentation : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Thanks @Yvan1263 The issue was with CORS, I have added following code in function.php file and it worked.
`

function add_cors_http_header(){
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
}
add_action('init','add_cors_http_header');

`